# Why does CONVERT to datetime break for this query but not the other?

Tags: sql-server-2012

This query works fine:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, GroupAdminEffectiveDate, 101) from ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
group by GroupAdminEffectiveDate
```

and returns the following:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
2012-06-30 00:00:00.000
2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
2012-07-11 00:00:00.000
2012-07-23 00:00:00.000
2012-07-25 00:00:00.000
2012-08-01 00:00:00.000
2012-08-14 00:00:00.000
2012-08-26 00:00:00.000
2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
2012-09-03 00:00:00.000
```

However, the following query:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, GroupAdminEffectiveDate, 101) from ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
```

and I get the following the error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

UPDATE:

Query:

```
select distinct GroupAdminEffectiveDate from ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
```

Result:

```
(empty string)
06/30/2012
07/01/2012
07/11/2012
07/23/2012
07/25/2012
08/01/2012
08/14/2012
08/26/2012
09/01/2012
09/03/2012
```

Comment: what is the type of GroupAdminEffectiveDate?

Comment: What is the data type of `GroupAdminEffectiveDate`? Why isn't it a DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: It's a VARCHAR... unfortunately the system that I do not have control over stores it as a VARCHAR

Comment: Try the 2nd query without the CONVERT, and check for values that might not convert properly (contains AM/PM, slashes instead of dashes, etc...)

Comment: 2nd query without the convert shows valid dates and empty strings

Comment: empty string cannot convert to date.(the error)

Comment: @habibzare, but select CONVERT(DATETIME, '', 101) returns 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: Are you sure it's empty string and not tab or carriage return / line feed or some non-printable character? I can't seem to reproduce your error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I tried copying directly from the result... also, if it was the case.. when i do the 'group by' shouldn't that fail as well?

Comment: Yes that's why I think there is something going on here that you're not telling is. But I don't know what it might be so I don't know what further information to ask you for. Can you script the table using SSMS' Generate Scripts... wizard so that it scripts the table (including collation and indexes) and inserts for the actual data?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment is a View.. does that make a difference?

Comment: Maybe, could you tell us all of the information up front instead of making us pull teeth?

Comment: Please add your view definition to the question.

Comment: And it would also be helpful if you could add the execution plans for both your queries. The issue is liklely that you get different execution plans and you have invalid date values in your tables and the conversion is executed before the bad date rows are filtered out in your failing query.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, I will update the question shortly..

Comment: Sorry @AaronBertrand, I was not intentionally hiding information from you.. I simply did not realize that the fact that it was a view mattered... to give you all the information to solve the problem up front is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error, so I suspect our definition of "empty string" differs or there is something else going on that you haven't revealed. In the meantime, since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `TRY_PARSE` for this, e.g. one of these expressions:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us') 
  FROM dbo.ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment;

SELECT TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us') 
  FROM dbo.ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
  GROUP BY GroupAdminEffectiveDate;

SELECT TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us') 
  FROM dbo.ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
  GROUP BY TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us');
```

If you really want the 1900-01-01 to be a valid output, then:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us'),
    '19000101') 
  FROM dbo.ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
  GROUP BY TRY_PARSE(GroupAdminEffectiveDate AS DATETIME USING N'en-us');
```

Comment: Still not sure why the query doesnt work, but this will work for what I need

Answer (score 0):

There might be that there are more 'non-date' fields in your database. One can be `""` and another `" "`. When you group by or distinct, all end up being `""` which implies NULL, and that is good to convert.
Otherwise it fails for `" "` (space).

check `select length( GroupAdminEffectiveDate ) from ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment`
Maybe it will give you some clue?

Answer (score 0):

You first CAST your `varchar` column to `Datetime` and then CONVERT.

```
Declare @testvarchar VARCHAR(15) = '08/27/2012'
select CONVERT(datetime, Cast(@testvarchar as datetime), 101)
```

That should solve your conversion error

Answer (score -2):

check this:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, ISDATE( GroupAdminEffectiveDate), 101) from ExchangeSmallGroupEnrollment
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do? it just ends up converting either 0 or a 1 to a date.... 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 or 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000